# How do I read mesos logs ? I mean can somebody please explain whats the meaning of each argument?

Tags: logging, logstash, mesos, mesosphere

```
I0909 22:47:01.240753 21904 sched.cpp:635] Scheduler::statusUpdate took    23007ns
I0909 22:47:01.240617 21904 master.cpp:3600] Sending 1 offers to framework 20140909-224659-16842879-44263-21883-0000
```

What is I0909? What is the date/timestamp format used? What pattern does it use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a default format of glog libraray

```
 [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line]
```

For example

```
I0909 22:47:01.240753 21904 sched.cpp:635] Scheduler::statusUpdate took    23007ns
```

- I  -- Level
- 09 -- month
- 09 -- date
- 22 -- hour
- 47 -- minute
- 01 -- second
- 240753 -- micro second
- 21904  -- thread id
- sched.cpp -- source file
- 635       -- source file line
- Scheduler::statusUpdate took    23007ns -- message

Answer (score 1):

Now, @haosdent has already provided the concrete answer. Just for the sake of completeness, we're using [glog](https://github.com/google/glog) in Apache Mesos for logging.